# (Не) обязательно. Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Например: ... и для того, чтобы помочь, (не) обязательно лезть в душу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.. и для того, чтобы помочь, не обязательно лезть в душу.Мне видится здесь отрицание, я бы написала раздельно.А вообще, критерий отрицательного или утвердительного смысла в предикативных наречиях на -о устанавливается самим пишущим.